# Small HTTPS portable client

Tags: http, client

I need a HTTP client that supports HTTPS. I need to embed it in my game client, so it should be as small as possible. CURL is way too big for my needs. I use C/C++, and I need portability with Windows and Linux (on Mac & iOS I use native web clients). Could you recommend some library?

I've found http://scumways.com/happyhttp/happyhttp.html but it doesn't support HTTPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to use Wininet on Windows. But never make the same mistake I did, this library is ultimately crappy. Its only advantage is it's built in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

qLibc implements HTTP client in C because of the needs that you just mentioned. It's small. It supports HTTPS(openssl based). I'm one of the contributors. Check it out if that fits your need. => [qLibc](https://github.com/wolkykim/qlibc)

+1 please if this helped.